# Run FxCop against ASP.net web-site?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, fxcop

How can I run FxCop against an ASP.net Web-site?

### Background

I have an ASP.net Web-site that I want to run FxCop against.

**Note**: I have an ASP.net web-site, not an ASP.net web-application, that I want to run FxCop against.

How can I run FxCop against an ASP.net web-site in Visual Studio 2010 Professional?

---

[Some people suggest](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/737febfb-c142-4056-bf82-728d58ce8760) that it's very simple: just right-click the web-site project, and click **Run Code Analysis on Web Site**:

> The process it very simple.... just right click on the web site project and "Run Code Analysis on Web Site"

What they ignore is that [no such option exists](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/737febfb-c142-4056-bf82-728d58ce8760):

[image]

---

I also tried **Tools** menu -> **FxCop**. But of course that doesn't work because its command line options:

```
FxCopCmd.exe /c /f:$(TargetPath) /d:$(BinDir) /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\Rules"
```

Doesn't make sense for web-sites.

---

[Someone has suggested](http://www.webpronews.com/using-fxcop-with-aspnet-2006-12), correctly, that it's not possible, because there is no assembly for FxCop to validate:

> The build process in ASP.NET 2.0 is very different than in ASP.NET 1.x, because it does not produce a dll file.
>
> That means that you cannot use FxCop because it can only work with dll and exe file types.

That means that short of compiling the entire web-site into an assembly, you cannot run FxCop against an ASP.net web-site.

How can I run FxCop against an ASP.net web-site?

Comment: Aside: You may want to move your note from the bottom of the question to the top, since I didn't read it until after I had read everything after the first separator :).

Comment: The moral of the story is to stop using little toys like the web site "project". Use a web application project, and all of this just works.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The downsides of that option ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)) easily out-weigh being able to run FxCop.

Comment: Not being able to run FxCop is the least of the downsides of web  sites. Sorry to not be able to list them out, but all of those downsides come from the fact that Web Site "projects" are unique among all the other project types in Visual Studio. It's not good to be unique. For instance, they are always the last to be tested, and if some feature doesn't work with a web site, chances are that nobody cares enough to make it work.

Comment: @JohnSaunders If a web-application could be compiled down to ASPX and CS files, so they can be viewed, and updated, individually from the rest of the web-site it would be okay. But a single assembly containing all the code is a deal breaker. i can still unit-test an asp.net web-site; i just can't FxCop it.

Comment: There are other things you won't be able to do. Among other things, here's a hint you may already have learned: when asking for help, always tell people you're using a web site. Hopefully people will know what that is. Otherwise, they'll assume you're using a web application project and will give you answers that won't work for web sites.

Comment: @JohnSaunders See line #3 (the **Note**) in the question.

Comment: @IanBoyd: I saw that. No big deal, but I've noticed here that most people have never used web sites, so, even if they see that you're using one, they don't know all the weird effects of that, so may give you answers that apply to every other kind of .NET application - but which will therefore not apply to web sites, which are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to pre-compile your web site,

1. Pre-compile your web site using aspnet_compiler.exe, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860(v=vs.100).aspx
2. Run FxCop on the result of precompilation.

You could not see the "Run Code Analysis on Web Site" because your Visual Studio edition is not high end enough (Microsoft should be blamed as such essential features should be there in all editions).

Comment: Accepted as *not possible*.

Comment: I would recommend that you select the `Use fixed naming and single page assemblies` option to make it easier to map back to the source. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860(v=vs.100).aspx#PreCompilingToFixedNameAssemblies

Answer (score 1):

You can publish your website, it will generate dlls on which you can run fxcop.

[Use-FxCop-with-ASPNET-20](http://madskristensen.net/post/Use-FxCop-with-ASPNET-20.aspx)

---

The build process in ASP.NET 2.0 is very different than in ASP.NET 1.x, because it does not produce a dll file. That means that you cannot use FxCop because it can only work with dll and exe file types. However, there is a way to produce dll files from your web application within Visual Studio 2005 and those dll files can be used by FxCop.

These are the steps to follow to make FxCop analyse your web application:

**Step 1**

Create a new folder somewhere on the disk. It could be C:\deploy

**Step 2**

Publish the web application into the new folder

[image]

[image]

**Step 3**

Open FxCop and add all the dll files from the newly created bin folder (C:\deploy\bin) to be analyzed.

[image]

For those of us not using Visual Studio Team System, these are the steps we need to follow to analyse our web applications in FxCop. Let’s hope the next version of Visual Studio have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can run a tool that does analysis on source code, not compiled assemblies. Might save some of your valuable time.

Comment: Unfortunately most analysis tools such as FxCop, Mono Gendarme, NDepend require binaries/assemblies.

Comment: Indeed, this is why with NDepend we suggest to compile the web site to analyze it http://www.ndepend.com/FAQ.aspx#ASPNET

Comment: Our product http://submain.com/CodeIt.Right is different and analyzes source code.